# Bootstrap accordion collapse button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I'm trying to make a bootstrap accordion with an internal button that will collapse the current accordion segment and open the next one, this for some reason is not working.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">  
    <accordion>
       <accordion-group id="firstpanel" heading="Static Header 1"  is-open="status.isFirstOpen">
          <span id="span1">This content is straight in the template.</span><br> 
          <button id="nextpanel">Next</button>
       </accordion-group>
       <accordion-group heading="Static Header 2">
          <span id="span1">This content is straight in the template.</span>
       </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    isFirstDisabled: false
  };

  $("#nextpanel").on("click", function() {   
   $(firstpanel).click();
  });
}
```

I have made a plunker example here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ag4O5Rli1XaydI05AI7c?p=preview)

Comment: What do you mean "for some reason" ? What have you done to implement closing of the current accordion and opening the next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use jquery selectors inside controller constructors. DOM elements like `#nextpanel` are not even in the DOM tree at that phase, so `$("#nextpanel")` is essentially an empty array.

I suggest you forget about jquery alltogether. The only case for jquery, is maybe when you need to use a plugin you are already familiar with (like a calendar). In any case, jquery code (the one with the `$()`) should stricktly reside in the link function of the directive that wraps the plugin.

The MVC way, is to have a "model" (JS object) drive the UI. Angular will do its magic to keep the two synced.

A model that stores which accordion is open could simply be an array of booleans:

```
$scope.status = [true, false, false, false];
```

Opening the next accordion is simply finding which one is opened, and set to true the next one (or wrap around to the first one).

```
$scope.next = function() {
    var indx = $scope.status.indexOf(true);
    $scope.status[(++indx) % $scope.status.length] = true;
};
```

The accordion component will make sure that only one of them is `true` at any given time.

Now, your template is something like:

```
<accordion>

    <accordion-group heading="Static Header 1"  is-open="status[0]">
      <span>This content is straight in the template.</span><br>
      <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
    </accordion-group>

    <accordion-group heading="Static Header 2"  is-open="status[1]">
      <span>This content is straight in the template.</span><br>
      <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
    </accordion-group>

    <accordion-group heading="Static Header 3"  is-open="status[2]">
      <span>This content is straight in the template.</span><br>
      <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
    </accordion-group>

    <accordion-group heading="Static Header 4" is-open="status[3]">
      <span>This content is straight in the template.</span><br>
      <button ng-click="next()">Start over</button>
    </accordion-group>

</accordion>
```

Here is the fixed [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dcMJRNT1XmnwjN1hWuNX?p=preview).